# Jquery alert message not getting popped

Tags: jquery

Im a newbie to JQuery and trying this code but for some reason I don't see the alert button being popped..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
        <script src="C:/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
                    alert( "The link will no longer take you to jquery.com" );
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            a.test {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the jQuery library being loaded successfully? Do you get any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Is `C:/jquery/jquery.js` really a working path to jQuery?

Comment: To load from your local system, doesn't it have to be: `file:///jquery/jquery.js`? (And that's assuming your server has access to your local system's file-system.)

Answer (score 2):

I think that's not the right way to include the jquery script from your localhost, you can, for testing purposes (or even production) include it this way:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Remember to put in in your html header.

If you still want to include it from you local drive use this path:

```
file:///C:/jquery/jquery.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is ok, this should work.

Try to replace

```
<script src="C:/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

by

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```